# Pointing subdomains to different servers, how easy is it?

Tags: localization, subdomain

At some point in the life of a web application I'm developing, it may become a good idea to have identical copies of the site on servers in different parts of the world.

For example, customers in the US will have their data stored on a server in the US, whereas UK and the rest of Europe will have their data stored on one in Europe. This obviously isn't an issue right now but at some point we expect minimising the "round trip time" to be something we would need to do to help keep response times as fast as possible.

The way we want to do this is to have the portion of the site the members use set up with a region specific subdomain (eu.example.com, us.example.com, etc). How easy is this to do and what should I be considering in the design process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up the subdomains is a matter of setting the DNS records, and let them point to a different server for each subdomain. This is no problem at all!

If you have everything dublicate on each server, you should worry about syncing though.
Depends on the type of web application you write, this might be a bit tricky

Comment: Thanks :) Making sure the data is synced isn't a huge concern as the only thing that needs to be persistent apart from the site pages is the structure of the underlying database. The user's data will never have any need to go from one server to another.